# Azure AD B2C ASP .Net Core 2. Implementing both MVC and Web API on one site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

There are examples of the correct `Startup.cs` contents for a site using Azure AD B2C on MVC using ASP .Net Core 2 available, and other examples for implementing a Web API in .Net Core with Azure AD B2C. They are different.

Can I implement both on the same web app?
And if so what does the startup.cs look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. `Startup.cs` would have both authentication configurations.

See [Dotnet core 2.0 authentication multiple schemas identity cookies and jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778679/dotnet-core-2-0-authentication-multiple-schemas-identity-cookies-and-jwt)