# Asp.Net Core Use Cookie Authorization and JWT Authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cookies, jwt

I am facing a problem which I cannot seem to solve in my application. Right now I am using cookie authorization for the MVC part of my application and JWT Tokens for the Api. So far so good, everything works like expected; I am able to authorize my MVC controllers with the cookie authorization scheme and I am able to authorize my API with JWT authorization scheme.

**But here is the problem:** My views make Ajax requests to get some data from my Api. Every time a request is made, it gives me a not authorized error. This happens since the Api uses the JWT scheme. What is the best solution to go form here? Do I need to create a JWT token locally, save it in a separate cookie and then setting the authorization header before I send the request? Like so:

```
// Attatch token to all requests
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '@Request.Cookies["Token"].Value');
});
```

Or would I set the authorization scheme to JWT and cookies for the Api controllers?

---

**Startup.cs:**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie()
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidIssuer = _configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = _configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
        };
    });
```

---

**Edit:**

According to the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x), I am supposed to do it like this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

It still shows a 401 error if I send an Ajax request from my view. It does work when I send a request from Postman with the JWT token included.

I found out that if I set only the JWT bearer scheme, the scheme get applied correctly and works as expected for JWT tokens:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

But for the Cookie authentication it only works when I don't specify any scheme at all, like this:

```
[Authorize]
```

Doing this doesn't work:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

JwtBearerDefaults

Comment: You only need to use cookies if they're running on the same host.  Cookies will be sent with all requests including ajax requests.

Comment: But I still need the JWT authentication for the users that use the API like mobile devices, etc. How would I be able to set the authorization scheme to both JWT and Cookie?

Comment: @TomelSafadi you can set both schemes on ApiControllers [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778679/dotnet-core-2-0-authentication-multiple-schemas-identity-cookies-and-jwt#comment78727152_45853589)

Comment: I did it the way you described it. However, it does work for the JWT scheme but it does not work for the Cookie scheme. Setting only the JWT scheme works but it also does not work by setting only the Cookie scheme like this: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]. Cookie authorization only works by not specifying any scheme at all, like this: [Authorize]. Thoughts?