# Asp.Net Core Setting the Cookie Scheme explicitly doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, jwt, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to use both JWT scheme and Cookie scheme in my Authorization. Like described in the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x). When I do this, I can see that it works for requests using the JWT authorization. I tried this by making a request from Postman including a JWT token. Howver, it does not work for Ajax requests comming from the views of my site, thus making use of the Cookie authorization.

Narrowing down this problem, showed me that even if I explicitly specify the Cookie scheme, it doesn't work:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

It only works if I don't specify the scheme at all:

```
[Authorization]
```

This is my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidIssuer = _configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = _configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
        };
    });
```

Anyone else facing this problem? Or does someone know why setting the Cookie scheme explicitly doesn't work?

Comment: How is the cookie built ? Is the cookie generated by  `ASP.NET Core Identity`?  If that's the case, that cookie won't be used by your default CookieAuthenticationHandler. If not, could you please show us how you sign in the user to get a cookie?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Asp.Net Core Identity to generate my cookie. I don’t understand how it works though if I just put the [Authorize] attribute without anything. Do you know how to set it up the right way, when using Identity?

Comment: If you're using `Identity` to generate code, the default Scheme for Identity is `Identity.Application`, so change the code to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]` should make it. Note the cookie sent to the server should be `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8LZ4qAV8K....`

Comment: If you're interested in the reason:  The default cookie Name for plain cookie scheme is `.AspNetCore.Cookies` instead of `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application`. Also, the data protector for default cookie scheme is ` options.DataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", name, "v2");`.

Comment: Just curious about your design:  if you're using ASP.NET Core Identity, why register another cookie scheme again?

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for the detailed answers! I will implement it tomorrow and let you know if it worked.

Comment: What do you mean with registering another cookie theme? Do you mean the code from the startup.cs?

Comment: If you're using Identity, it will register a built-in cookie handler behind the scenes. You don't need register another one by `.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`

Comment: Yeah, I actually forgot to take that out as I was trying to figure out why it doesn’t work. You mean only the ‘CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme’ right? The ‘.AddCookie()’ I obviously need I assume? Sorry I am new to Identity....

Comment: In your case, there's no need to invoke`.AddCookie()` manually. The `Identity` does it for you. See [CookiesBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a677fd231e2f8e9d18749fc2a4761d1a724bc6c1/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityCookiesBuilderExtensions.cs#L51-L58)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the details!

Comment: Seems that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003265/asp-net-core-use-cookie-authorization-and-jwt-authorization) talks abut the same question. I've created a demo and now pretty sure it works fine for me.  If you still cannot make it, feel free to update me.

Comment: If I am running into more issues with Identity, I will come back to you:). You seem like you know a lot about it!